# Copying mask key frames but different shape

Tags: edit-mode, video, keyframes, masking, movie-clip-editor

can I copy keyframes of one mask to another but with different starting shape? I need to move it only in x-axis and y-axis, I mean no need to further change the shape. Just to like parent this mask of 1st one. If yes, please tell me how. 
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

In the movie clip editor.

Select the vertices of the mask you want to move, then shift-select one of the control points of the other mask and press Ctrl+P to parent.

For example: this mask is parented to a tracking point.

[image]

If I create a second mask, and parent it to one of the points of the first mask, then they both move together.

[image]

If you don't want to create a new mask but duplicate an existing one. Just select the mask, and hit shift+D to duplicate it and move it where you want, all of the atributes and keyframes of the original mask will be duplicated.

[image]